# Periodic task celery every world minute

Tags: python, django, celery

The celery tasks stops every minute, but the countdown starts from the time when I start the celery. Can I create a periodic task that will be executed every minute of time (like on a clock) and not related to when I started the task.

```
@app.on_after_configure.connect
    def setup_periodic_tasks(sender, **kwargs):
    sender.add_periodic_task(60.0, do_something.s(), expires=10)
```

Now it work like this, I'am started celery on 10:10:24 (H:M:S):

```
do_something - 10:11:24
do_something - 10:12:24
do_something - 10:13:24
do_something - 10:14:24
...
```

But I want to see

```
do_something - 10:11:00
do_something - 10:12:00
do_something - 10:13:00
do_something - 10:14:00
...
```

exactly at 00. Can I do that with easy way? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [crontab](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#crontab-schedules) schedule

> If you want more control over when the task is executed, for example,
>   a particular time of day or day of the week, you can use the crontab
>   schedule type